# IntEnum returning AttributeError: can't set attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, class, enums

That is an unsettling problem. For the function:

```
def influencePositive(q1, q2):
    if(q1.magnitude.greaterZero()):
        q2.derivative.value = DValue.add(q2.derivative.value, 1)
```

The following unit test runs without issues:

```
def test_i_plus_active(self):
        q1 = Quantity(Magnitude(MValue.PLUS), None)
        q2 = Quantity(None, Derivative(DValue.ZERO))

        r.influencePositive(q1, q2)
        self.assertEqual(q2.derivative.value, DValue.PLUS)
```

But for this other function:

```
def exogenous(q1, q2, value):
    if type(value) == int:
        q2.derivative.value = DValue.add(q1.derivative.value, value)
```

The following unittest breaks:

```
def test_ex_increase_minus(self):
        q1 = Quantity(None, DValue.MINUS)
        q2 = Quantity(None, DValue.MINUS)

        r.exogenous(q1, q2, 1)
        self.assertEqual(q2.derivative.value, DValue.ZERO)
```

It raises a Atribute error: AttributeError: can't set attribute. That is the whole traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Victor Zuanazzi/Documents/Artificial Intelligence/Knowledge Representation/Practicals/Qualitative_Reaoning/relationFunction_test.py", line 121, in test_ex_increase_minus
    r.exogenous(q1, q2, 1)
  File "C:\Users\Victor Zuanazzi\Documents\Artificial Intelligence\Knowledge Representation\Practicals\Qualitative_Reaoning\relationFunctions.py", line 31, in exogenous
    q2.derivative.value = DValue.add(q1.derivative.value, value)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\types.py", line 146, in __set__
    raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Here is some background knowledge to understand the above code.

DValue is an IntEnum:

```
from enum import IntEnum

class DValue(IntEnum):
    MINUS = -1
    ZERO = 0
    PLUS = 1

    @staticmethod
    def add(dvalue, delta):
        return max(min(dvalue + delta, DValue.PLUS), DValue.MINUS)
```

We use that to set the class Derivative:

```
class Derivative:
    def __init__(self, value):

        #if value is type int, it is converted to Enum.
        if value is int:
            value = DValue(value)

        self.value = value
```

Quantity is a class that has a magnitude and derivative values set to it's instances:

```
from magnitude import Magnitude, MValue
from derivative import Derivative, DValue

class Quantity:
    def __init__(self, magnitude, derivative):
        self.magnitude = magnitude
        self.derivative = derivative
```

I don't see why `influencePositive()` works just fine and `exogenous()` breaks. They both call `DValue.add()` in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your issue:

In the case of your first test, the derivative is a `Derivative` object, whose `.value` attribute can be reassigned. In your second test, the derivative is a `DValue` (`IntEnum`) object, whose `.value` attribute cannot be reassigned.

```
In [4]: d = Derivative(DValue.ZERO)

In [5]: d.value
Out[5]: <DValue.ZERO: 0>

In [6]: d.value = 1

In [7]: d.value
Out[7]: 1

In [8]: d = DValue.MINUS

In [9]: d.value
Out[9]: -1

In [10]: d.value = 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-3c0164b4d46d> in <module>()
----> 1 d.value = 1

/home/ethan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enum/__init__.pyc in __set__(self, instance, value)
     54 
     55     def __set__(self, instance, value):
---> 56         raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
     57 
     58     def __delete__(self, instance):

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

So I think your second test should set up `q2` like this maybe:

```
q2 = Quantity(None, Derivative(DValue.MINUS))
```

Comment: It worked! It became obvious after you pointed out, I was just completely blind to it.

Comment: yeah, it was kind of subtle since both classes have a `.value`!